# Couchbase lite on Android, retrieve views

Tags: android, listview, couchbase-lite

This question is about Couchbase lite (no Sync Gateway).

I'm new to Couchbase, I managed to use the [demo app](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/training/develop/create-database/index.html?language=android), but I don't understand it completely.
It contains this code which (as far as I understand, since I'm not native English speaker) retrieve views to populate a listview with the indexes:

```
    // This code can be found in ListsActivity.java
    // in the setupViewAndQuery() method
    com.couchbase.lite.View listsView = mDatabase.getView("list/listsByName");
    if (listsView.getMap() == null) {
        listsView.setMap(new Mapper() {
            @Override
            public void map(Map<String, Object> document, Emitter emitter) {
                String type = (String) document.get("type");
                if ("task-list".equals(type)) {
                    emitter.emit(document.get("name"), null);
                }
            }
        }, "1.0");
    }

    listsLiveQuery = listsView.createQuery().toLiveQuery();
```

**Could anyone give me a hand with what each part is doing?**

**In which step is the listview populated**

**Can I change "list/listsByName" in the code (line 3)? What would happen?**

**Can I emit more than one element?**

Comment: Have you looked at the Couchbase training here: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/training/index.html? If you have questions, feel free to post to the Couchbase forums.

Comment: @Hod That is precisely where I got that piece of code from, and what my question is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is a little bit convoluted.  Let's answer the easy parts first.

> Can I change "list/listsByName" in the code (line 3)?

Yes.  That's just the name of the Couchbase View.  You choose the View name.  Unfortunately the terms used in Couchbase and Android overlap some.  A Couchbase View is a kind of static index of your database.

> Can I emit more than one element?

Yes.  You can emit most anything you want.  Take a look at the documentation [here](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/view/index.html)

Now, tracing how the Android ListView gets updated:

In `ListsActivity.java` notice in the onCreate method a `ListAdapter` instance gets added to the `ListView`.  This `ListAdapter` is a private inner class that extends `LiveQueryAdapter`.

`LiveQueryAdapter` is in the `utils` subpackage.  If you look at its constructor, you'll see it adds a change listener to the query passed in.  When triggered, this change listener sets an enumerator equal to the rows passed back by the live query, then calls `notifyDataSetChanged` to tell the list to refresh itself.  That, in turn, causes `getView` in `ListAdapter` to get called.  That's where the data is pulled from the database and used to populate a list entry.

Comment: In `ListsActivity.java` there is a definition of `ListAdapter`. Do I have to include it in my code for it to work or it's done by CB?

Comment: You have to include it in your code.  `ListAdapter` is an inner class in `ListsActivity`, so you can take a look at the code for it.